# GCSE Maths Question - Probability please help.

Tags: probability

I am having an issue with this question. Usually, I am good at these, but as a class, we were set this as a challenge. It might be easy for you lot but:

2n + 1 counters are in a bag:
n are red, the rest are blue.
Show that the probability of a different colour is (n + 1 / 2n + 1)

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a homework solving site. What have you tried?

Comment: If there are $2n+1$ counters in a bag and $n$ of them are red, then $(2n+1)-n$ of them are a color different than red.  Now, assuming each counter is equally likely to be selected, taking the ratio of the number of not-red counters to the total number of counters gives you your desired probability.

Comment: I have tried: ((n / 2n + 1) x (? / 2n + 1)) = n + 1 / 2n + 1    But the thing is, I don't know what the probability of getting a Blue is thus, I can't show that the two probabilities x together then added to itself is equal to n + 1 / 2n + 1

Comment: @JMoravitz I meant the probability of getting Blue, Red and Red, Blue = n + 1 / 2n + 1

Comment: In that case, you need to correct your question to explain what exactly is occurring.  The original phrasing of the question sounded like you simply wanted to ask "*what is the probability of drawing a color other than red in a single draw?*" to which the calculation is a simple $1-Pr(red)=1-\frac{n}{2n+1}=\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$.  It sounds from your comment that you are instead asking about "*What is the probability that when drawing two consecutive balls without replacement that one be red and the other be blue in either order?*"

Comment: For that, your above attempt at a calculation is incorrect.  Take a different example where I have eight balls, six of which are red and two are blue.  The probability of a red ball *followed by* a blue draw will be $\frac{6}{8}\times \frac{2}{7}$.  Similarly, the probability of a red ball followed by a red ball will be $\frac{6}{8}\times\frac{5}{7}$.  Notice how the numerator and denominator can change from one to the other.  These are dependent events.  Worded a different way, after having taken a ball out in the first step, there are fewer balls in the bag to pull from...

Comment: ...and we base our calculations for the later step on the *new* number of balls of each color in the bag after having removed whichever color in the first step.  So, if there are $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls out of $2n+1$ balls total, the probability of a red followed by a blue is $\frac{r}{2n+1}\times\frac{b}{2n}$.  Do you know the value of $r$ and the value of $b$ for this problem?  You should...

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps using numbers might help. For example: if there are 14 counters in a bag, 4 are red and the rest are blue. Show the probability of a different color is $\frac{10}{14}$. Are you able to see it now? If choosing a counter is equally likely, then the probability of choosing a blue counter is $\frac{10}{14}$ since there are 10 counters which are equally likely to be selected.

However, instead of the numbers I showed you with, they give you variables. So, $2n+1$ *total* counters, $n$ of which are red, this implies that $(2n+1)-n$ are the number of blue counters. This yields $n+1$ blue counters. (notice that the total probability will be the number of red counters + the number of blue counters which is $n + (n+1) = 2n+1)$ which is what is stated in the beginning of the problem.

So the probability of choosing blue counter is this number of blue counters/total number of counters which is $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$

Comment: Thanks this really helps.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to find the probability of choosing $2$ balls of different colour.

In that case.
The probability is=$1-[\mathbb{P}(R)+\mathbb{P}(B)]$
Where $\mathbb{P}(R)$=Probability that both balls are Red and $\mathbb{P}(B)$=Probability that both balls are Blue.

Now $\mathbb{P}(R)$=$\frac{n(n-1)}{(2n+1)(2n)}$

Now $\mathbb{P}(B)$=$\frac{n+1)n}{(2n+1)(2n)}$

hence the Answer is $1-\frac{n(n-1)}{(2n+1)(2n)}-\frac{n+1)n}{(2n+1)(2n)}$=$\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)}$

And that's your answer